# Digit Date Range

Tags: code-golf, number, date

*NOTE: Since I'm Dutch myself, all dates are in the Dutch `dd-MM-yyyy` format in the challenge description and test cases.*

### Challenge:

**Inputs:**
Start date \$s\$; End date \$e\$; Digit \$n\$

**Outputs:**
All dates within the range \$[s,e]\$ (including on both sides), which contain \$n\$ amount of unique digits in their date.

**Example:**

*Inputs:* Start date: `12-11-1991`; End date: `02-02-1992`; Digit: `4`

*Outputs:*
With leading 0s for days/months:

```
[20-11-1991, 23-11-1991, 24-11-1991, 25-11-1991, 26-11-1991, 27-11-1991, 28-11-1991, 30-11-1991, 01-12-1991, 02-12-1991, 09-12-1991, 10-12-1991, 13-12-1991, 14-12-1991, 15-12-1991, 16-12-1991, 17-12-1991, 18-12-1991, 20-12-1991, 23-12-1991, 24-12-1991, 25-12-1991, 26-12-1991, 27-12-1991, 28-12-1991, 31-12-1991, 01-01-1992, 02-01-1992, 09-01-1992, 10-01-1992, 11-01-1992, 12-01-1992, 19-01-1992, 20-01-1992, 21-01-1992, 22-01-1992, 29-01-1992, 01-02-1992, 02-02-1992]
```

Without leading 0s for days/months:

```
[20-11-1991, 23-11-1991, 24-11-1991, 25-11-1991, 26-11-1991, 27-11-1991, 28-11-1991, 30-11-1991, 3-12-1991, 4-12-1991, 5-12-1991, 6-12-1991, 7-12-1991, 8-12-1991, 10-12-1991, 13-12-1991, 14-12-1991, 15-12-1991, 16-12-1991, 17-12-1991, 18-12-1991, 20-12-1991, 23-12-1991, 24-12-1991, 25-12-1991, 26-12-1991, 27-12-1991, 28-12-1991, 31-12-1991, 3-1-1992, 4-1-1992, 5-1-1992, 6-1-1992, 7-1-1992, 8-1-1992, 10-1-1992, 13-1-1992, 14-1-1992, 15-1-1992, 16-1-1992, 17-1-1992, 18-1-1992, 20-1-1992, 23-1-1992, 24-1-1992, 25-1-1992, 26-1-1992, 27-1-1992, 28-1-1992, 31-1-1992]
```

### Challenge rules:

- The input and output dates may be in any reasonable (date-)format. Can be as a string in any `dMy` format (including optional separators), list of three integers, your language's native Date-object, etc. Output may be a list/array/stream, printed to STDOUT, a single delimited String, etc.
- You are allowed to include or exclude leading 0s for days/months in your outputs. **Please specify which of the two you use in your answer**, since it will cause different results. I.e. `1-1-1991` has 2 unique digits, but `01-01-1991` as 3 unique digits.
- You don't have to deal with leap years and differences of Gregorian vs Julian calendars. You can assume the date-ranges given in the test cases will never go over February 28th/March 1st for years divisible by 4.
- The input-digit \$n\$ is guaranteed to be in the range \$[1,8]\$, so dealing with \$n=0\$ is unspecified (returning an empty list would be most reasonable, but giving an error or incorrect result is fine as well; you won't have to deal with that input).

### General rules:

- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so shortest answer in bytes wins.
  Don't let code-golf languages discourage you from posting answers with non-codegolfing languages. Try to come up with an as short as possible answer for 'any' programming language.
- [Standard rules apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/default-for-code-golf-program-function-or-snippet/2422#2422) for your answer with [default I/O rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/), so you are allowed to use STDIN/STDOUT, functions/method with the proper parameters and return-type, full programs. Your call.
- [Default Loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden.
- If possible, please add a link with a test for your code (i.e. [TIO](https://tio.run/#)).
- Also, adding an explanation for your answer is highly recommended.

### Test cases:

```
Inputs: [12-11-1991, 02-02-1992], 4
Outputs with leading 0s:    [20-11-1991, 23-11-1991, 24-11-1991, 25-11-1991, 26-11-1991, 27-11-1991, 28-11-1991, 30-11-1991, 01-12-1991, 02-12-1991, 09-12-1991, 10-12-1991, 13-12-1991, 14-12-1991, 15-12-1991, 16-12-1991, 17-12-1991, 18-12-1991, 20-12-1991, 23-12-1991, 24-12-1991, 25-12-1991, 26-12-1991, 27-12-1991, 28-12-1991, 31-12-1991, 01-01-1992, 02-01-1992, 09-01-1992, 10-01-1992, 11-01-1992, 12-01-1992, 19-01-1992, 20-01-1992, 21-01-1992, 22-01-1992, 29-01-1992, 01-02-1992, 02-02-1992]
Outputs without leading 0s: [20-11-1991, 23-11-1991, 24-11-1991, 25-11-1991, 26-11-1991, 27-11-1991, 28-11-1991, 30-11-1991, 3-12-1991, 4-12-1991, 5-12-1991, 6-12-1991, 7-12-1991, 8-12-1991, 10-12-1991, 13-12-1991, 14-12-1991, 15-12-1991, 16-12-1991, 17-12-1991, 18-12-1991, 20-12-1991, 23-12-1991, 24-12-1991, 25-12-1991, 26-12-1991, 27-12-1991, 28-12-1991, 31-12-1991, 3-1-1992, 4-1-1992, 5-1-1992, 6-1-1992, 7-1-1992, 8-1-1992, 10-1-1992, 13-1-1992, 14-1-1992, 15-1-1992, 16-1-1992, 17-1-1992, 18-1-1992, 20-1-1992, 23-1-1992, 24-1-1992, 25-1-1992, 26-1-1992, 27-1-1992, 28-1-1992, 31-1-1992]

Inputs: [19-09-2019, 30-09-2019], 5
Outputs (same with and without leading 0s): [23-09-2019, 24-09-2019, 25-09-2019, 26-09-2019, 27-09-2019, 28-09-2019, 30-09-2019]

Inputs: [19-09-2019, 30-09-2019], 8
Output (same with and without leading 0s): []

Inputs: [20-06-1749, 30-06-1749], 8
Outputs with leading 0s:    [23-06-1749, 25-06-1749, 28-06-1749]
Outputs without leading 0s: []

Inputs: [10-12-1969, 12-01-1970], 6
Outputs (same with and without leading 0s): [30-12-1969]

Inputs: [10-12-1969, 12-01-1970], 5
Outputs with leading 0s:    [10-12-1969, 13-12-1969, 14-12-1969, 15-12-1969, 17-12-1969, 18-12-1969, 20-12-1969, 23-12-1969, 24-12-1969, 25-12-1969, 27-12-1969, 28-12-1969, 31-12-1969, 02-01-1970, 03-01-1970, 04-01-1970, 05-01-1970, 06-01-1970, 08-01-1970, 12-01-1970]
Outputs without leading 0s: [10-12-1969, 13-12-1969, 14-12-1969, 15-12-1969, 17-12-1969, 18-12-1969, 20-12-1969, 23-12-1969, 24-12-1969, 25-12-1969, 27-12-1969, 28-12-1969, 31-12-1969, 2-1-1970, 3-1-1970, 4-1-1970, 5-1-1970, 6-1-1970, 8-1-1970, 12-1-1970]

Inputs: [11-11-1111, 11-11-1111], 1
Output (same with and without leading 0s): [11-11-1111]
```

Comment: I know it is specifically not the format demanded here, but I just comment here to "spread the word": there is an internationnal standard that programmers should try to use for dates (in logs, filenames, etc) : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601. (uses a 'T' to desambiguate (without the T the date+time could be something else entirely) and specifies the separators to use, and when one can not use separators [ie proposes different variant (from short to long] of the same standard]: the main one being: `YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.mmm +hh:mm`, the +hh:mm being your locale's time offset from UTC .)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 23 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

Takes the date inputs as Unix timestamps, outputs an array of strings with formatting and leading `0`s dependent on your locale. Would be 1 byte shorter in Japt v2 but there seems to be a bug when converting `Date` objects to strings.

```
òV864e5@ÐX s7Ãf_¬â Ê¶WÄ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&header=0FVxLSB3KW4K0FZxLSB3KW4&code=8lY4NjRlNUDQWCBzN8NmX6ziIMq2V8Q&input=IjEyLTExLTE5OTEiCiIwMi0wMi0xOTkyIgo0Ci1S)

```
òV864e5@ÐX s7Ãf_¬â Ê¶WÄ     :Implicit input of integers U=s,V=e & W=n
òV                          :Range [U,V]
  864e5                     :  With step 86,400,000 (24*60*60*1000)
       @                    :Map each X
        ÐX                  :  Convert to Date object
           s7               :  Convert to locale date string
             Ã              :End map
              f             :Filter
               _            :By passing each through the following function
                ¬           :  Split
                 â          :  Deduplicate
                   Ê        :  Length
                    ¶       :  Is equal to
                     WÄ     :  W+1, to account for the inclusion of the delimiting "/" or "-"
```

Answer (score 5):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 81 bytes

```r
function(s,e,n,x=seq(s,e,1))x[lengths(sapply(strsplit(paste(x),""),unique))==n+1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYoxCgIxEEXvkmoGs2IWmy3SeQuxCMtEA2HM7kwgnj5mrYRXfN77e4@@x8qrpjeDWLJsmxfaftshtnsmfupLQEIp@QOiu5ScFEoQJWhojUFbOW2VEL3nk3v0CEHOtzC6ccviJjeYx@3fztPlYNgr9i8)

Uses R’s native date format and has leading zeros on day and month.

Answer (score 3):

## [Red](http://www.red-lang.org), 93 bytes

```
func[a b n][until[if n = length? exclude d: rejoin[a/4"-"a/3"-"a/2]"-"[print d]b < a: a + 1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jYxBCsIwFET3PcWQrXyapLWSongHtyGL2CQaKVFKC94@pgouXAmf@bN48ybv8sk7barQI4clDdrijGT0kuY46hiQcMDo02W@HuGfw7g4D9dj8rd7TNrWLSNm6@ad0pSnH1NMM5w5Yw/bw2IDYUwOEJKEIKGUAJdUrlSJFp8BIyJWFUoRVyS5UGj4t3a/FKdVpzq1avmq3fE/KWzzCw)

Without leading 0s for days/months.

Too bad that [Red](http://www.red-lang.org) converts internally `09-10-2019` to `9-Oct-2019` - that's why I need to extract the day/month/year individually.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Red but it seems like there's a lot of whitespace that could be cut out of this. Pardon me if I'm wrong, though.

Comment: @connectyourcharger No problem! Seemingly there are several unnecessary whitespaces, but they are needed to separate the tokens. Words (identifiers) in Red can include `-=+*<>?!~&`, that's why a whitespace (or `(...)[...]"..."`) are needed.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3.8 (pre-release)](https://docs.python.org/3.8/), 84 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to Gloweye

```python
lambda s,e,n:[d for i in range((e-s).days+1)if-len(set(d:=str(s+type(e-s)(i))))==~n]
```

An unnamed function which returns a list of strings (counting/including leading zeros) that accepts three arguments:

- `s`, the *start* - a `datetime.date` object;
- `e`, the *end* - a `datetime.date` object; and
- `n`, the number of days - an `int` object.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY07DsIwEAV7TrHlWnEQIQhCJJ8EKIy8BkvxR/Y2bri6IemY7o2eNKnyO4ZxSrnZHD0YzcTOEzifYuZt76y6t0X7p9FQJMkw3wzYmMGBC5B1eBEi9UXsja6lG4Sz/UIBCzGaWRXOWDquibYTOvFDqU94tJRdYLS4VnC4nK4SzhKOByHhX42rmoRoXw)**

Note: As the function accepts `datetime.date` objects I have not counted the import code for that (and have worked around importing the `datetime.timedelta` object as it is indirectly accessible via subtraction of these input objects).

Comment: `type(obj)` is 3 bytes shorter than `obj.__class__`.

Comment: @Gloweye awesome thanks!

Comment: @Gloweye saves 6 in the end (the dot goes and the brackets are already present)

Comment: I hadn't analyzed to that depth yet, just saw the `__class__` and made a quick comment. Always glad to help.

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/) `-rdate`, 54 bytes

Takes 2 [Date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html) objects and a number as input, and returns a list of Date objects as output. Handles leap years and uses leading zeroes.

```ruby
->a,b,n{(a..b).select{|d|d.to_s.chars.uniq.size==n+1}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBBbsMgEEX3OQXyKlEZxLipUxbuqrewrApsoliKsGvwoo1z9dIxTZuoq3zN5qEH88U4mY@4LyO8aG64O621EGYjvD3aJpzmdm5F6N@8aA569GJy3bvw3actS/eA53OsVoxSZagUAuaAmHG2UA5yGaJtzS9SLlGBVIBqkX7pURI93SM9/0m429JxAblM6y70X1KFSp1@JLWTIJeSRMU90rUTUiBNkm4JSaqF1c2BtT2bNWeGMzeni8MUPNtXrzpYMdD32bXecHaDhtDV9CRck62sa@NXP4Sudz7C2JL/DQ)

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), 91 bytes

Takes input as `(n)(end)(start)`, where the dates are expected as Unix timestamps in milliseconds. Returns a space-separated list of dates in format `yyyy-mm-dd`.

Leading 0s are included.

```javascript
n=>b=>g=a=>a>b?'':(new Set(d=new Date(a).toJSON().split`T`[0]).size+~n?'':d+' ')+g(a+864e5)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rZFBS8MwGIbv/orckhC@kq923SIku@zkQQ/zJsKyNSsdJRlr2MCDf7226MRWNgSF75Dw8D7ke7OzR9tsDtU@gg@Fa7e69dqstSm11caa9ZzSO@bdiSxdZIXuTwsbHbM8ieF@@fjAeNLs6yqunlbP8qW7VK9OvPk@VwhKKBcls2KWZ27C203wTahdUoeSUQBDKBFkyzLOxJeZolIpyH4oHwME7KYH/OaCbDLIpBIVSAW3ciQ7A1TXZOo/ZbPhNtOsy@Q/ZWeQymuyfFTNVIL8rGYI8u5ZKaD8fWd/lOEwg/jxaTiWfQe8fQc)

Comment: This snippet will probably fail if DST shifted happened (a+864e5 may not be tomorrow in that case). But thankfully, tio use UTC timezone which doesn't have DST. -- from someone who use the same logic in product website and realize something wrong until DST shifted...

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 90 bytes

```php
for([,$s,$e,$n]=$argv;$s<=$e;)$n-count(count_chars($d=date(Ymd,86400*$s++),1))||print$d._;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZHPT4MwFMfv/BUvS5OBa2eLDKiMePbk2TCyEKgysxVCixfn346lw22JHta8NO/bfN7PtnU7rJ/aunUcpIXSClLIHDAnmzOfMEYY52yOYU59Yswo36ggx78QJ5QTnzI@Qg/0Sq1ugfgZ8s1zSFgUnKGzii@ZKBnb4qGFjEvHDiNqVHgLdNUTs9OZY6FrxQyUJ47z1nSiKGtwp9UUCqznwZdNIsq6gdmzbHv9CDNYwkezk@4Mg7EJXMJsI196fUISG4aULjptFq10pxu9O4hTgYzmHtxDHAaUTqSQ1T8c@8MV3fvn@HOy3@/xVADb8KmTzM/zZDADuRlGCiOBkcxTG5cgtU6RSDwkSdn0Urv23pZ10SkXVWlVaOG@HipsK94htVh4mHne8dh2O6lRtdwmw2UfG7mRZtLvYYh4vBpiGkZD8AM)

This is with leading 0s. Inputs are command arguments (`$argv`) and dates are Unix timestamps in days (basically standard seconds / 86400), I used this format as we don't need the time in this challenge and it allowed me to golf 1 more byte. Keeps adding a day to start until it reaches the end and prints any dates with `$n` unique digits in it, separated by `_` in `Ymd` format.

Also have a [89 bytes alternative](https://tio.run/##jZHPb4MgFMfv/hUvhqS6QgfOqsw2O@@082JNY5TNLi0awV3W/e0OqWubbIe@EHhf8nm8H7R1O6ye2rp1HKSF0grWkDlgLJuxgDBGGOdshmFGA2KWUYFRYY5/IU4oJwFlfIQe6JVa3gLxMxSY64iwODxDZ5VcXqJkLItHFjIuHSuMqVHRLdBVTcx2Z8xC14oZKE8d563pRFHW4E2jKRRYz4cv@4go6wbcZ9n2@hFcWMBHs5Oei8GsCVyAu5EvvT4hqQ1DShedNoNWutON3h3EKUFGcx/uIYlCSidSyOofjv3hiu79c/w52e/3eEqAbfhUSRbkeTqYhrwMI4WRwEjmaxuXIrVaI2GO@dxHkpRNL7Vn921ZF53yqkIL7/VQYZvyDikfM98/HttuJzVSi206XMaxkRtpGv0ehpgnyyGhUTyEPw) which prints dates to output in same format as input (Unix timestamps in days).

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), 86 bytes

```java
(s,e,n)->s.datesUntil(e.plusDays(1)).filter(d->(""+d).chars().distinct().count()==n+1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVRtb5swEP6eX3FCjWRWbGHapSMZ@dRWmrRIk7p9mKp88MAkZGAQNt2qKr89O5u8NttUg4yfu@defD6zEk@CrrKfm6Jq6tbACjEzRSXZ5zoV5a0wcjI40@V1WwnDrPYr4nsHjWxPqZ0pSqZNK0XF3k0Gg7QUWsNMFApeBgCFQotcpBLuHQZ4cNyP@8hTyMkegA7gAGRg7UH5E7RcD3Bquh9lkYI2wuDnqS4yqDAUQaeFWjzOQbQL7YNZtvUvDXe/U9mYolbb0PeQQ7IhOpCB8ulUswyj6G8Kt0Aka8pO34pnTbjvs7woMXGS0SnxvMvMZ@lStJr4LCu0KVRqcJnWncJvkqhL7m8mu925RDAVdG00JNvYdrx4PKKcUx7H3AvACyOKL6LIomtvHRxTYxrGNAp5bJVX4TF6/3bqh1NqhMoR5TfXe@oBvaLykNp045FT4jK0md@EFo3eTn2dK3cVwOGop2hHXffFPGs9yM4kyTmL1fkXt1DEyzI6m9EOh@f3TrGt4dAv9pBg3J@Vvz@qo37EAHvEGuwBSSz5MZwH59lsQxw7kP9ywP/rwPU9mn7C@7PALTlDBL1tNEfilvnwrI2sWN0Z1uCmTE48nQz5hcmonSs3fw9AJsPICSMnjJxQJcOri2yosPp48/C@qX0GOcvJTmb/BXciXZJDsPHYRSsPBn9JZKj6Z1f7dX@P15s/)

I chose to use leading `0`s.

### Credits

- -24 thanks to [Kevin Cruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) who didn't know he could golf away that much :p

Comment: Maybe I shouldn't have made it inclusive on both ends, then you could have used Java 9's `datesUntil` for [103 bytes](https://tinyurl.com/y4mk6jr3). ;) Nice answer. I don't see anything that could be golfed personally.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Well, actually, you gave an extremely nice way of golfing! Just add `.plusDays(1)` and remove the `.forEach(System.out::println)` and it's a very much golfed answer because as you wrote, dates can be returned as value objects and streams are allowed. ;-) I had no clue that `datesUntil` even existed! Thank you for that :-)

Comment: Woops, forgot about my own rules allowing stream returns, haha XD I'm an idiot. But glad I could help you with my idiocy. ;p

Answer (score 1):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc)

## Without leading 0s, <s>104</s>, 103 bytes

```cs
(s,e,n)=>new int[(e-s).Days+1].Select((x,i)=>s.AddDays(i)).Where(x=>$"{x:yyyMd}".Distinct().Count()>=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xdLPS8MwFAfwu39FCB4S@hqaOn/U2YJYBcWeFHaYO9T2TQNbBk2KLbK/vaZqh2wXPQxJICHf98gHksL4hVHdTa2LizS3@KiWCJuN0hZur3W9xCp/XuCmIknInMQdM4CgeZxofCOudsrQN1ykeWs8ORMPuMDCMtaAcjVGXJZlHzHFuZi8YoWsIXFySN@b87Zts3JNRaqMVdo1cXG1qrVbk1jzbkwOJpWyeK80MjqlxCPGVkq/iLuV0owCBTJnvWIQMhlFEqSbIQeynYTghjsf8QHZS8gnpSz9LPMdqF1Tzj06I0@a8vGfAWEgIwgikNE2YEiOApcc/z/hbI8EeTpyF51AGOw8w3eyf4KUXz9B7hB@JvL3hO4D)

## With leading 0s, <s>106</s> 105 bytes

```cs
(s,e,n)=>new int[(e-s).Days+1].Select((x,i)=>s.AddDays(i)).Where(x=>$"{x:yyyMMdd}".Distinct().Count()>=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##xdLPS8MwFAfwu39FCB4S@hqaOn/U2YJYBcWeFHaYO9T2TQNbBk2KLbK/vaZqh2wXPQxJICHf98gHksL4hVHdTa2LizS3@KiWCJuN0hZur3W9xCp/XuCmIknInMQdM4CgeZxofCOudsrQN1ykeWs8ORMPuMDCMtaAcjVGXJZlHzHFuZi8YoWsIXFySN@b87Zts6ws11SkylilXRsXV6tauzWJNe/G5GBSKYv3SiOjU0o8Ymyl9Iu4WynNKFAgc9Y7BiOTUSRBuhlyINtJCG648xEfmL2FfGLK0s8y35HaNeXcozPypCkf/xkQBjKCIAIZbQOG5ChwyfH/E872SJCnI3fRCYTBzjN8J/snSPn1E@QO4Wcif0/oPgA)

Comment: You can remove the space at `x =>$"` in both your versions for -1. :)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen ah fuck thanks x) I'm sure someone can come up with a shorter solution too, I'm not satisfied with this one

Answer (score 0):

## Kotlin, 119 bytes

```
fun f(a:LocalDate,b:LocalDate,c:Long)=a.datesUntil(b.plusDays(1)).filter{it.toString().chars().distinct().count()==c+1}
```

Without leading 0s, takes in two `java.time.LocalDate` and a `Long`, returns a `Stream` of `LocalDate`s

Comment: Hi, welcome to CCGC! Could you perhaps add a [Try it online](https://tio.run/#kotlin) link with test code to verify it works? Also, I don't know Kotlin, but is it possible to replace `it.toString()` with `(it+"")` to save a few bytes? I know this is possible in some other languages like Java or .NET C#.